# Move div to another div when screen is less then 992px and move it to original place for greater then 992px screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now, I am moving div tag to another div tag when screen is less then 992px. But if screen is again greater then 992px, it should be placed again at original position.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
  <div id="translate-this">
    <a class="translate-this-button" href="//www.translatecompany.com/translate-this/">Translate This</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {   
      $("#top").appendTo("#bottom");
    } else {  
      $("#bottom").appendTo("#top");
    }
  }); 
});
```

When I decrease window size of browser, it moves div element to another div element with bottom id, but when I again make window full size, it does not move div with top id to its original place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make the screen smaller than 992, `#top` gets appended inside of `#bottom`, converting the html to this

```
<div id="bottom">
 <div id="top">
  <div id="translate-this"><a class="translate-this-button"  href="//www.translatecompany.com/translate-this/">Translate This</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then when you make the screen larger, you try to execute `$("#bottom").appendTo("#top");`. that would try to append `#bottom` inside of `#top`, which makes no sense, since `#bottom` has `#top` inside

You can move the `translate-this` div around like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {   
   $("#translate-this").appendTo("#bottom");
}
else {  
   $("#translate-this").appendTo("#top");
}
```